# Change eclipse quotes text color

Tags: eclipse, fonts, colors

i have dark theme installed (DevStyle Theme) on Eclipse, and the text in the quotes is pretty hard to read, I Cannot find how to Change it, i tried changing some of the colors in preferences but it doesn't seem to work, how can i change this, thank you.

- EDIT: I found the correct setting, the onclick is actually javascript, the setting is under Javascript->Editor->Syntax Coloring -> Element -> Strings

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello! A DevStyle developer here :). Can you let me know which editor are you using? It's known that some editors use hardcoded colors instead of theme friendly ones. So DevStyle cannot intercept the corresponding color preferences. 

From the code itself it looks like an HTML editor, do you happen to know if it's a third party editor or the same Eclipse comes with?

Comment: If using the Generic editor (WWD) yuo can check in preferences under Web > HTML Files > Editor > Syntax Coloring

Comment: Default editor, the file is .jsp, I cannot find the appropriate setting for onclick="text", neither in HTML Files nor JSP Files